# "FB is not defined" in Internet explorer (Facebook API)

Tags: javascript, facebook

I get this error "FB is not defined" when i try to run this code in Internet Explorer:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
          share(accessToken,uid);
        } else {

           FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                var uid = user.id;
                var name = user.name;
                var email = user.email;
                var gender = user.gender;
                var birthday = user.birthday;
                var username = user.username;
                var link = user.link;

            });
           } else {
             alert('Du skal acceptere');
           }
         }, {scope: 'email', display: 'iframe'});


        }   
   });
```

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this. It's working in every other browser than Internet Explorer 7&8

Comment: How are you including the JS SDK?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uwQF6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fiddle, the reason you cannot get it to work in IE7 and 8 is because of the trailing space in the comma separated list of `oauth : true,}` in your FB.init().  Some browsers are forgiving of this syntax error, but others like IE are not.  Fix the syntax issue and you should be fine.